# Problems with XmlPullParser code inside an AsyncTask (Activated By Button Click)

Tags: eclipse, android-asynctask, xmlpullparser

SO I have a program that I have been working on for a while.  However, I am stuck on method that uses `XmlPullParser`, the method is called `getAllXml()`.  It is inside of the `doInBackGround()` method of an `AsyncTask`. The  `AsyncTask` is a subclass of an Activity called `FormActivity`.  When I run the code.

Here is what the code is supposed to do.  After the user selects `"CloverField"` from a previous activity.  An xml file called `cloverfield_in.xml` is called by `setContentView()`.  The user then presses a button on this same xml file.  Clicking this button executes the `AsyncTask` called `MadLIbAsyncTask`.  Within this `AsyncTask` this are only two methods, the `doInBackground()` and the `onPostExecute()`.  (I don't know if I need `onPreExecute()`...within which I would have have a progress bar....but without this method I figure the program shouldn't crash the way it does).

Within the `doInBackground()` method, I am calling the method called `getAllXml()`. This method uses `XmlPullParser` to search through the current xml (`cloverfield_in.xml`) and capture text from a single `TextView`.  The code for `getAllXml()` is as follows.

```
public void getAllXml() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
    Activity activity = this;

    Resources res  = activity.getResources();
    XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.layout.cloverfield_in);
        int eventtype = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventtype != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT){


            }
            else if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                if (xpp.getName() == "TextView"){
                    while (eventtype != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
                        if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
                        stringViews[0] =  xpp.getText(); 
                        }else {}
                        eventtype = xpp.next();

                    }
                }else {}
            }
            else if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.END_TAG){

            }
            else if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
            }
            eventtype = xpp.next();
        }
}
```

When in the process of debugging, my program often returns a `NullPointerException` or a `RunTimeException`.  I believe within this code is where the problem resides.  I tested the `AsyncTask` without the existence of the `getAllXml()` method and everything works fine. Eventually the program is supposed to take the text gathered from the `cloverfield_in.xml` file and display it in a new file called `cloverfield_out.xml`.

For a complete review of everything, here is the entire code for `FormActivity.class`.

```
package com.muirconsult.mymadlibs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FormActivity extends Activity{

        String [] textFields;
    String Choice;
    int thisLayout;
    View thatLayout ;
    String[] stringViews;
    ViewGroup anskey;
    Activity activity = this;
    String test;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent objIntent = getIntent();
        Choice = objIntent.getStringExtra("selection");

        if (Choice.equals("Cloverfield")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.cloverfield_in);
            thisLayout = (R.layout.cloverfield_in);
            thatLayout = (View)findViewById(R.layout.cloverfield_out);

        }
        if (Choice.equals("Fargo"))  {
            setContentView(R.layout.fargo_in);
        }
        if(Choice.equals("Ying Yang In This Thang (Ying Yang Twins)")){
            setContentView(R.layout.ying_yang_twins_in_this_thang_in);

               }


    }

public void getAllXml() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
    Activity activity = this;

    Resources res  = activity.getResources();
    XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.layout.cloverfield_in);
        int eventtype = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventtype != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT){


            }
            else if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                if (xpp.getName() == "TextView"){
                    while (eventtype != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
                        if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
                               stringViews[0] =  xpp.getText(); 
                        }else {}
                        eventtype = xpp.next();

                    }
                }else {}
            }
            else if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.END_TAG){

            }
            else if (eventtype == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
            }
            eventtype = xpp.next();
        }
}





 class MadLibAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String testString;
    int thisLayout;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try{
        getAllXml();
    }catch (XmlPullParserException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute (Void result){
        String str = "let's go to the park";
        String newstr;

        setContentView(R.layout.cloverfield_out);
        TextView outview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outview);
        str = (String) outview.getText();
        newstr = str.replaceFirst("film",stringViews[0]);
        outview.setText(newstr);

    }
 }








     public void onClick(View view) {
                MadLibAsyncTask mad = new MadLibAsyncTask();
        mad.execute();


     }

}
```

Also, most importantly...the logcat looks as such:

```
08-10 23:04:50.064: W/dalvikvm(1415): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception >>>  (group=0x40a71930)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): java.lang.NullPointerException

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendEvaluated>(Matcher.java:130)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:110)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceFirst(Matcher.java:299)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:1793)
08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at com.muirconsult.mymadlibs.FormActivity$MadLibAsyncTask.onPostExecute(FormActivity.java:116)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at     com.muirconsult.mymadlibs.FormActivity$MadLibAsyncTask.onPostExecute(FormActivity.java:1)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600>\ (AsyncTask.java:177)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at     android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

08-10 23:04:50.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show us the logcat from the crash. For now, I can tell you that `xpp.getName() == "TextView"` is not how you compare strings in Java, use `.equals()`. Also, you never initialize `stringViews` to an array.

Comment: Why shouldn't I initialize stringViews to an array?

Comment: Not that you shouldn't but that you never initialise it in the code you've shown. The problem is the str.replaceFirst line, put a breakpoint there and check the value of each parameter.